# how I make my opera browser run the mouse pointer

Tags: html, css, frontend

So I have developed a basic website which runs on old feature phones as well as smartphones. Now on a feature phone, at times, a mouse pointer appears via which it makes it easier for the user to scroll and select certain options on the website. I have tried replicating the process but I have been unable to do so. It always happens randomly. I would love to know what I can add to my code to get the mouse pointer permanently active. Keep in mind I cant use Javascript as the feature phone I am testing on does not have JS and this is also the case for most of my users.

[image: This is without the mouse pointer. The user is only getting an option to highlight the various options they can click]

[image: The pointer appears automatically when the user clicks on different options. There is no set pattern to it.]

Comment: We can't help without seeing the problem, so post a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `cursor: pointer` in the CSS for whichever element you want to display the cursor for. For the whole document, that would be:

```
body {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey added the code in the css for the whole document but i am still facing the same issue as before. I have added images of the problem i am facing.

Comment: Could you post your HTML / CSS in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please? I can't be sure why your implementation isn't working without seeing the code producing the problem. There's no reason why my answer shouldn't work, but you may have a rule with higher specificity interfering. As a 'hack' solution, you could add `!important` to ensure that it overrides (almost) everything else.